# q-item no manteien seleccionada una opcion

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

Tengo un formulario en donde cree un q-select desplegable con q-item en su interior, pero al momento de seleccionar un elemento de la lista secundaria, esta no queda seleccionada, este es mi componente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es mi código:

```
 <q-select
              class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 tt-input__nolabel"
              outlined
              :options="itemsDeuda"
              v-model="form.deuda"
              @filter="filterFn"
              use-input
              fill-input
              input-debounce="0"
              autocomplete="off"
            >
            <template v-slot:option="scope">
            <q-expansion-item
            expand-separator
            group="somegroup"
            header-class="text-weight-bold"
            :label="scope.opt.label"
            @click="cargarItemSelector(scope.opt.value)"
            >
          <q-item
          v-for="c in itemsGasto"
          :key="c.label"
          v-ripple
          select
          clickable
          use-input
          fill-input
          v-model="form.gasto"
         @click="c.value"
          >
          <q-item-section>
            <q-item-label clickable v-html="c.label"></q-item-label>
          </q-item-section>
          </q-item>
        
          </q-expansion-item>
            
            </template> 
          
          </q-select>
```

Comment: Es vue 3? sí es así puedo ayudar con una respuesta modificando el código.               La razón es la siguiente: Viendo el código la lógica en el select está equivocada ya que no está asignando nada al **select**: `v-model="form.deuda"` y aún si quisiera los q-item no son entrada, es decir: ` v-model="form.gasto"` no tiene sentido...

Comment: La solución vendría usando el event click de  q-expansion-item y q-item para asignar los valores de las dos listas, luego usando ``watch()`` con matriz múltiple, vigilar las elecciones de las listas e insertarlas al v-model del select manteniendo las elecciones. (tenga en cuenta que con esto para form.deuda, form.gasto debe crear el propio acceso (por eje: otro watch para asignar del select a ellos) ). Sería útil la respuesta?

Comment: no me queda del todo claro, podrías darme un ejemplo de codigo?

Comment: Doy por echo que es vue 3 para crear la respuesta, bueno.

Comment: disculpa olvidé mencionarte eso, si, es Vue 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es importante entender el funcionamiento de **[v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#multiple-v-model-bindings)** para aplicarlo en un select cuyo caso es el enlace entre la elección de un option.

**Problema:**

Como comenté, el select cuenta con el enlace: `v-model="form.deuda"` (no es especifico), el cual almacena el valor de elección por options, que por defecto sería la primer lista. Para la
lista secundaria `v-model="form.gasto"`, cuyo enlace no se implementa para `q-items:` [Documentación: q-items](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/list-and-list-items).

Aunque tiene enlace con `form.deuda` a la primer lista, es claro por el código que la intención es usar

1. *q-select:*  `v-model="form.deuda"` para la primer lista
2. *q-item:* `v-model="form.gasto"` para la segunda lista

Y esta lógica no es correcta:

- No hay v-model especifico para el select.
- No hay enlace entre listas al select.
- Solo esta renderizando la segunda lista (Ahorro general, ahorro...)

**Solución:**

Recreo los valores de las listas: `itemsDeuda` e `itemsCosto`. Claro, solo tendría que modificar según su codigo. Dejo el ejemplo listo para ver enseguida, copie y pegue.

```
<div>
    <q-select
      class="
        col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12
        tt-input__nolabel
      "
      v-model="valueSelect" 
      :options="itemsDeuda"
      outlined
      use-input
      fill-input
      input-debounce="0"
      autocomplete="off"
    >
      <template v-slot:option="scope">
        <!--Se asigna el valor a formDeuda -->
        <q-expansion-item
          expand-separator
          group="somegroup"
          header-class="text-weight-bold"
          :label="scope.label"
          @click="
            () => {
              (formDeuda = scope.label), consoleDeuda(scope.label);
            }
          "
        >
          <!--Se asigna el valor a formCosto -->
          <q-item
            v-for="c in itemsGasto"
            :key="c.label"
            v-ripple
            select
            clickable
            use-input
            fill-input
            @click="
              () => {
                (formCosto = c.value), consoleCosto(c.value);
              }
            "
          >
            <q-item-section>
              <q-item-label clickable>{{ c.label }}</q-item-label>
            </q-item-section>
          </q-item>
        </q-expansion-item>
      </template>
    </q-select>
</div>

<script setup>
import { ref, reactive, watch } from "vue";

const valueSelect = ref([]); //Select

const formDeuda = ref(""); //Primer lista
const formCosto = ref("sin elegir"); //Segunda lista


const itemsDeuda = reactive(["deuda1", "deuda2", "deuda3"]);
const itemsGasto = reactive([
  { label: "general", value: 1 },
  { label: "navidad", value: 2 },
  { label: "vacaciones", value: 3 },
]); //Recreo los valores. Cambie según su código.

watch([formDeuda, formCosto], ([newD, newC]) => {
  console.log(`Deuda es ahora: ${newD} y costo: ${newC}`);
  valueSelect.value = [newD, newC];
});

//Con estos eventos puede ver la reactividad en consola
const consoleDeuda = (op) => {
  console.log(op);
};
const consoleCosto = (op) => {
  console.log(op);
};
</script>
```

**Modificaciones:**

1. `select:` valueSelect - v-model ahora especifico.
2. `q-expansion-item:` Primer lista- evento @click
3. `q-item:`  Segunda lista- evento @click

Como lo comente, aplicar el evento @click en *q-expansion-item* y *q-item* para asignar los valores de las dos listas a `formDeuda` y `formCosto`. Luego usando watch() con matriz, se vigilan las elecciones de las listas insertándolas al v-model del select: `valueSelect`. Esto permite mantener las elecciones de las dos listas en el select.

Comment: Muchas gracias! te has pasado con la explicación e implementación, me ha funcionado perfectamente! nuevamente muchas gracias!

Comment: Genial, saludos!